# Unicoherence of the two-dimensional sphere

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

A connected space $X$ is said to be *unicoherent* if for any two closed connected subspaces $A$, $B$ such that $A\cup B = X$ then $A\cap B$ is connected.
I came across an exercise which asks to show that $I=[0,1]$ is unicoherent, that $S^1$ is not, and to determine whether $S^2$ is unicoherent or not. The first two questions are quite easy (any connected subspace of $I$ is either a point or an interval, whose intersection is again a point or an interval, and for $S^1$ the sets $A=S^1\cap\{(x,y) : x≥0 \}$, $B=S^1\cap\{(x,y) : x≤0 \}$ make a counterexample).
However I have not been able to find a proof for the last one. I am certain the answer is positive, as $S^2$ "has no holes", but I don't know how to show that. Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about homology theory?

Comment: Hint: Could you solve this with "closed" replaced with "open" for your subsets?

Comment: There are various ways to prove it; what book is this coming out of?  Is this in a general topology course or an algebraic topology course?  The theorem isn't trivial, it's WAY harder than the other two - not even in the same league.  Classical techniques will use the "Phragmen-Brouwer Properties" or the theory of essential maps and degrees of sphere maps.  You can find these proofs in Kuratowski's Topology II, Nadler's Continuum Theory, Voxman and Christensen's Aspects of Topology or Wilder's Topology of Manifolds.

Comment: You can also look at the proofs of the "Plane Separation Theorem", which is a generalization you get from the proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem.  That's basically the same as the Phragmen-Brouwer stuff, and it's in Munkres.  It follows formally from the Plane Separation Theorem.

Comment: Also I should warn you that "doesn't have holes" isn't a good way to understand unicoherence.  In general it's NOTORIOUSLY hard to prove that any given space, aside from the most absolutely trivial, are unicoherent.  For example, there is a compact, connected subset of the plane which is *hereditarily unicoherent*, i.e. every one of its closed, connected subsets is unicoherent, yet it separates the plane.  It's called the pseudo-circle.  Unicoherence is a very picky property that only behaves well for locally connected spaces.

Comment: @JohnSamples The exercise is from a batch made out of several General Topology books; not sure which one this is from. I see now that the problem is out of reach for me for now (this is my first year learning anything Topology related). I was expecting this kind of answer, actually. Thank you very much for your explanation and for providing references, I hope this can be useful to someone else and for me in the future.

Comment: Yeah, the theory of unicoherence for non-locally-connected spaces is basically non-existent, still.  It's a very difficult area without a lot of new ideas.